# Contract Address is not Showing and How to Send ETH from Contract Address to Contract Creator

Tags: solidity, address.transfer

**Q-1**: I,m new in Ethereum Bockchain,I have Created my new token that can be get by send from 0.01 to 1 ETH instant. When i did transaction in transaction hash Tokens Transferred From line showing 0x000000000.. 
If any need to addition in solidity code please suggest. Below is code and transaction hash.

**Q-2:** When anyone buy token instant to send 0.01 to 1 ETH than ETH going to my contract address and i don't know how i can send into creator address . Please help how i can send to my creator address.

**Transaction Hash** : https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe937a79a7b428ccb156011fde4e967ff0ad344aa91d22ac4bd58f9b4d6bb9da5

**Solidity Code:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;



/**
 * @title SafeMath
 * @dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error
 * Name : Techno Bit (TBIT)
 * Decimals : 8
 * TotalSupply : 10000000000
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
library SafeMath {

    /**
    * @dev Multiplies two numbers, throws on overflow.
    */
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        c = a * b;
        assert(c / a == b);
        return c;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Integer division of two numbers, truncating the quotient.
    */
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
        // uint256 c = a / b;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
        return a / b;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Subtracts two numbers, throws on overflow (i.e. if subtrahend is greater than minuend).
    */
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        assert(b <= a);
        return a - b;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Adds two numbers, throws on overflow.
    */
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
        c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
    }
}

contract ForeignToken {
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant public returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool);
}

contract ERC20Basic {
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    function balanceOf(address who) public constant returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public constant returns (uint256);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract TechnoBit is ERC20 {

    using SafeMath for uint256;
    address owner = msg.sender;

    mapping (address => uint256) balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;    

    string public constant name = "Techno Bit";
    string public constant symbol = "TBIT";
    uint public constant decimals = 8;

    uint256 public totalSupply = 10000000000e8;
    uint256 public totalDistributed =  1000000000e8;    
    uint256 public constant MIN_CONTRIBUTION = 1 ether / 100; // 0.01 Ether
    uint256 public tokensPerEth = 20000000e8;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

    event Distr(address indexed to, uint256 amount);
    event DistrFinished();

    event Airdrop(address indexed _owner, uint _amount, uint _balance);

    event TokensPerEthUpdated(uint _tokensPerEth);

    event Burn(address indexed burner, uint256 value);

    bool public distributionFinished = false;

    modifier canDistr() {
        require(!distributionFinished);
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }


    function TechnoBit () public {
        owner = msg.sender;    
        distr(owner, totalDistributed);
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
        if (newOwner != address(0)) {
            owner = newOwner;
        }
    }


    function finishDistribution() onlyOwner canDistr public returns (bool) {
        distributionFinished = true;
        emit DistrFinished();
        return true;
    }

    function distr(address _to, uint256 _amount) canDistr private returns (bool) {
        totalDistributed = totalDistributed.add(_amount);        
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
        emit Distr(_to, _amount);
        emit Transfer(address(0), _to, _amount);

        return true;
    }

    function doAirdrop(address _participant, uint _amount) internal {

        require( _amount > 0 );      

        require( totalDistributed < totalSupply );

        balances[_participant] = balances[_participant].add(_amount);
        totalDistributed = totalDistributed.add(_amount);

        if (totalDistributed >= totalSupply) {
            distributionFinished = true;
        }

        // log
        emit Airdrop(_participant, _amount, balances[_participant]);
        emit Transfer(address(0), _participant, _amount);
    }

    function adminClaimAirdrop(address _participant, uint _amount) public onlyOwner {        
        doAirdrop(_participant, _amount);
    }

    function adminClaimAirdropMultiple(address[] _addresses, uint _amount) public onlyOwner {        
        for (uint i = 0; i < _addresses.length; i++) doAirdrop(_addresses[i], _amount);
    }

    function updateTokensPerEth(uint _tokensPerEth) public onlyOwner {        
        tokensPerEth = _tokensPerEth;
        emit TokensPerEthUpdated(_tokensPerEth);
    }

    function () external payable {
        getTokens();
     }

    function getTokens() payable canDistr  public {
        uint256 tokens = 0;

        // minimum contribution
        require( msg.value >= MIN_CONTRIBUTION );

        require( msg.value > 0 );

        // get baseline number of tokens
        tokens = tokensPerEth.mul(msg.value) / 1 ether;        
        address investor = msg.sender;

        if (tokens > 0) {
            distr(investor, tokens);
        }

        if (totalDistributed >= totalSupply) {
            distributionFinished = true;
        }
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant public returns (uint256) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    // mitigates the ERC20 short address attack
    modifier onlyPayloadSize(uint size) {
        assert(msg.data.length >= size + 4);
        _;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyPayloadSize(2 * 32) public returns (bool success) {

        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_amount <= balances[msg.sender]);

        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_amount);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyPayloadSize(3 * 32) public returns (bool success) {

        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_amount <= balances[_from]);
        require(_amount <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);

        balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_amount);
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_amount);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _amount);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        // mitigates the ERC20 spend/approval race condition
        if (_value != 0 && allowed[msg.sender][_spender] != 0) { return false; }
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant public returns (uint256) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    function getTokenBalance(address tokenAddress, address who) constant public returns (uint){
        ForeignToken t = ForeignToken(tokenAddress);
        uint bal = t.balanceOf(who);
        return bal;
    }

    function withdraw() onlyOwner public {
        address myAddress = this;
        uint256 etherBalance = myAddress.balance;
        owner.transfer(etherBalance);
    }

    function burn(uint256 _value) onlyOwner public {
        require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
        // no need to require value <= totalSupply, since that would imply the
        // sender's balance is greater than the totalSupply, which *should* be an assertion failure

        address burner = msg.sender;
        balances[burner] = balances[burner].sub(_value);
        totalSupply = totalSupply.sub(_value);
        totalDistributed = totalDistributed.sub(_value);
        emit Burn(burner, _value);
    }

    function withdrawForeignTokens(address _tokenContract) onlyOwner public returns (bool) {
        ForeignToken token = ForeignToken(_tokenContract);
        uint256 amount = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        return token.transfer(owner, amount);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `withdraw()` function to transfer the ETH sent to the contract to the owner account.

```
function withdraw() onlyOwner public {
    address myAddress = this;
    uint256 etherBalance = myAddress.balance;
    owner.transfer(etherBalance);
}
```

Comment: already added this function but how to withdraw from myetherwallet using contact function ?

Answer (score 0):

**Ans 1** : You are supplying total supply of token must belong to some address *like Owner* and when we transfer that token it will emit transfer event witch specify `sender,receiver,amount` but in you case `sender = address(0) == 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. That's why this is showing you that address. For correction update `distr` function.

```
function distr(address _to, uint256 _amount) canDistr private returns (bool) {
    // Check owner has amount to transfer.
    require(balances[owner] >= _amount);
    totalDistributed = totalDistributed.add(_amount);        
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
    // Owner transfer amount and reduce token balance
    balances[owner] = balances[owner].sub(_amount);
    emit Distr(_to, _amount);
    // emit Transfer function (sender == owner)
    emit Transfer(owner, _to, _amount);

    return true;
}
```

**Ans 2** : You need to add `owner.transfer(msg.value);` in `getToken()` function.

```
function getTokens() payable canDistr  public {
    uint256 tokens = 0;

    // minimum contribution
    require( msg.value >= MIN_CONTRIBUTION );

    require( msg.value > 0 );

    // get baseline number of tokens
    tokens = tokensPerEth.mul(msg.value) / 1 ether;        
    address investor = msg.sender;

    if (tokens > 0) {
        // if token transfer to caller account, ether will be transfer to 
        // contract owner's account.
        require(distr(investor, tokens));
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    if (totalDistributed >= totalSupply) {
        distributionFinished = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yous so nice thanks .. i was use your rcommend code but now ETH going to owner wallet but buyer not getting tokens . can you tell me with same code that i was posted and also already withdraw function added . can you tell me how to withdraw from contract to owner wallet in myetherwallet contract>withdraw function ?